# Android : Deny button pressed on Bluetooth enabling dialog box

Tags: android, bluetooth

How do i handle the "**Deny**" button press on Bluetooth enabling Dialog box? I tried using `OnDismissListener` and `OnCancelListener` even tried `onActivityResult` but didn't work. The code is:

```
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (isBleSupportedOnDevice()) {
            initializeBtComponent();

        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    private boolean isBleSupportedOnDevice() {
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "BLE is not supported in this device.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void initializeBtComponent() {
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
```

This code prompts user with the dialog until he presses the "**Allow**" or "**OK**" button but i have to get back to previous activity once he presses "**Deny**" or "**Cancel**" button. How do i do this? is there any function that gets called when i press the "**Deny**" button?

Comment: I am having same issue.did you got any answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override onActivityResult method.

You are passing requestCode using constant REQUEST_ENABLE_BT

So when ever user presses the Allow or Deny button after that onActivityResult method will get called from your activity.

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
   startBluetoothStuff();
  }

 }
```

In above code check whether callback is for same request code.

So your ideal flow will be like something this

```
boolean isBluetoothManagerEnabled()
{
  // Some code
}

public void startBluetoothStuff()
{
   if(isBluetoothManagerEnabled())
   {
      // Do whatever you want to do if BT is enabled.
   }
   else
   {
       Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
       startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this method, the problem is "onResume" method gets called every time before "onActivityResult" method. So the user gets the dialog box again and again.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you simply check for ***RESULT_CANCELED*** in your **onActivityResult()** callback. Some thing like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
        ... Do your stuff...
    }
}
```